Square taper bottom bracket lock ring: grease, loctite, or both?
I removed the square taper bottom bracket on my bike today to regrease the threads to see if they're the culprit for an annoying creak I've been hearing while pedaling.
I can see that the outer 50% of the threads of the lock ring had blue thread lock / loctite from the factory:

When reinstalling the lock ring, should I put on new loctite, or just grease, or both? If just grease, should I grease all the threads or just the ones further inside the BB shell so the ones with loctite don't end up greased?
Thanks.

Looks like a Shimano BBUN-300. Shimano recommends greasing the metal threads on their square taper BBs without mentioning any regard to the blue stuff (1). Just search for "square taper" in the referenced source.
I would replace it if it I were you. Not worth doing the job twice if the unit itself is worn and these can wear fast(<4000km). Make sure to install it correctly with clean (and greased) threads in the shell and on the unit if you choose to reinstall it.
(1) https://si.shimano.com/en/dm/LAFC001/install_remove_bottom_bracket

Also, other Shimano bottom brackets with external cups come pre-greased, definitely not with preuapplied loctite. Otherwise it could become hell to release it in future.

The BBUN300 does come with this blue stuff on part of the threads on the NDS. Not sure excactly what it is or to what purpose. Seems rubbery, perhaps to make a better fit on worn threads, vibration dampening, water seal etc.

Blue “loctite” is for thread retention in that it gives some friction to keep the threads from vibrating out. Red loctite is for a permanent threaded interface that is not intended to be removed. Confusion arises because some precoated red threads aren’t permanent either.

Clean and grease the entire entire surface of the BB shell, including the threads. Use a light to moderate coating - too much won't hurt anything.
Grease is the approach that does the best job of protecting the frame and making removal go smoothly down the line.
Pre-applied threadlockers often have a hidden intention that can be easy to miss. If you're a component manufacturer, what happens to your parts is largely out of your hands after you make them. Bike assembly plants are the next step down the chain. If you were to put all your BBs out into the world with dry threads and say in your literature and manuals to prep the threads by greasing them, it's going to get skipped or done badly some amount of the time.
Most threaded interfaces on a bike, and BB threads are one of them, need only correct thread preload to stay in place and resist backing out indefinitely (there are very few exceptions to this). Grease on threads does two primary things: it protects from corrosion by sealing out moisture and preventing oxidation of the metals, and it facilitates a known torque input achieving a predictable amount of thread preload.
The thing about pre-applied threadlocker is that it does a better-than-nothing level job of some of the above things, and is also inherently a minor safeguard against poor assembly, and also has the benefit that if you're a factory making bike parts, it's easy to ship them with a layer of it. So manufacturers do that. Its presence is not necessarily a message that you shouldn't adulterate it. It's often just there to make sure something is there. On metal BB shells, you should basically always be adding lubrication.

Lubricating threads can also help prevent galling, especially here with the steel cup and aluminum BB shell threads. Aluminum's relative softness makes it prone to this type of damage.

~~Grease will negate the loctite.~~
Figured out that the blue stuff is most likely “vibra-tite”, and not loctite. Different applications, same color. :/
It’s possible the creak is coming from the bearings. If the BB is old, get a new one?

IIRC vibratite is just another brand name for thread locking compounds (much like loctite is). It is possible that this is a non-adhesive nylon patch (which might be what you're hinting at), but from what I remember this is indeed an epoxy-based threadlocker. Grease will negate it.

I always put only grease, never any threadlock. This has not resulted in any problems ever.
The key I think is torquing the bottom bracket cups enough. They need lots of torque. At least 40 newton-meters. Bottom bracket tools usually can be attached to a torque wrench, since they usually have a square head socket. I recommend a beam-type wrench such as Park Tool TW-2.2. They don't need to be calibrated and never go out of calibration therefore.
The bottom bracket threads are marginal anyway, so if you have an aluminum frame, do expect them to have a finite lifetime (with a steel frame there's a possibility only the aluminum BB threads wear out and not the steel BB shell threads, since aluminum is softer than steel). The forces in this interface are big, so threadlock may not improve lifetime.
